# Django Row_Number usage with group_by ORM

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm, window

I have a database(screenshot attached) and I want to retrieve the average of readings as per the aggregation size provided. Suppose my aggregation size is 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuHqy.png)

So, as per the image, there are four readings for a specific customer_id and device_id. I thus have to group two readings into one average reading row and again, the other two readings into another row.

```
    def get_aggregation_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    subq = queryset.annotate(row_number=Window(
    expression=RowNumber()
    # partition_by=2,
    # order_by=F('time').asc()
    ))
    
    outsubq = subq.annotate(group_id=((F('row_number') - 1)/ 2) + 1)
    
    queryset = outsubq.annotate(avg=Avg('reading'))
    return queryset
```

I am not able to apply group by on the group_id that I created using annotate.

Error that I am getting:
psycopg2.errors.WindowingError: window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you can't do `outsubq.annotate(avg=Avg('reading'))`?

Comment: When you look at the query, you see that your group_id field is replaced everywhere by `(RowNumber - 1)/ 2) + 1)` which cause Operationnal errors. It seems django will not rename your field, but replace it everywhere, which lead to the error.

Comment: The function is not returning the queryset that I want as output. I want the output as two rows each with average of 28.9 and 28.9 and another row with average reading of 14.9 and 24.9. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the internals of django are not doing what you think when combining annotation with Window functions. Filtering also doesn't work when combining window annotation.

I was trying querying and multiple example, just to see that there is a ticket here still open :

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333

As you can see, someone is using raw sql to perform what you want, and this is caused by the queryset not wrapping the window function args into a separate subquery.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But, if I try and use raw SQL query to extract the rows based on the group_id that I created, it doesnot give me Django Queryset instead it gives me a RawQueryset and I have no idea how to convert the RawQueryset to a Queryset. Any help is appreciated!